# Get data from ngResource and then bind result to view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngresource

I'm working on AngularJS project. I use ngResource to grab json data from a static file for now(might use db later on).

And then I use a controller to call the service using get(). I would like to bind the data in callback function to a $scope variable(gridData) in controller. However, it's failed and shown as undefined. Any suggestions? json data is pretty straight forward, just use an array with 0-10 as ids if you want to test using jsbin/plunker/whatever online editor.

controller:

```
'use strict';

var gridCtrl = appCtrl.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, dbService) {
    $scope.gridData = [];

    dbService.get(function (data) {
        $scope.gridData = data;
        console.log(data.jsondb);
    });
});
```

dataService:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app.services', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('dbService', function ($resource) {
        return $resource("/js/datafile/db.json");
});
```

Html View:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="character in $scope.gridData">
        {{character.id}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong: `<div ng-repeat="character in $scope.gridData">`

It should be:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="character in gridData">
        {{character.id}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I found that by myself after half an hour also... Good catch! Thanks!